# Regular expression to return all characters between two special characters

Tags: python, regex, parsing

How would I go about using regx to return all characters between two brackets.
Here is an example:

```
foobar['infoNeededHere']ddd
needs to return infoNeededHere
```

I found a regex to do it between curly brackets but all attempts at making it work with square brackets have failed. Here is that regex: `(?<={)[^}]*(?=})` and here is my attempt to hack it

```
(?<=[)[^}]*(?=])
```

**Final Solution:**

```
import re

str = "foobar['InfoNeeded'],"
match = re.match(r"^.*\['(.*)'\].*$",str)
print match.group(1)
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[`^.*\['(.*)'\].*$`](http://rubular.com/r/bgixv2J6yF) will match a line and capture what you want in a group.

You have to escape the `[` and `]` with `\`

The documentation at the rubular.com [proof](http://rubular.com/r/bgixv2J6yF) link will explain how the expression is formed.

Comment: Do I use this with re.search?

Comment: `a = re.search("^.*\['(.*)'\].*$","foobar['infoNeededHere']ddd")
print a.group()` is returning `foobar['infoNeededHere']ddd`

Comment: With regards to learning regex - my favourite tutorial is Chapter 8 of the [TextWrangler manual](http://pine.barebones.com/manual/TextWrangler_User_Manual.pdf). It's very easy to read and introduces regex concepts and syntax in a logical progression, with lots of examples. I keep a copy of that chapter around my desk at all times.

Answer (score 70):

If you're new to **REG**(gular) **EX**(pressions) you learn about them at [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html). Or, if you want a gentler introduction, you can check out the [HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html). They use Perl-style syntax.

### Regex

The expression that you need is `.*?\[(.*)\].*`. The group that you want will be `\1`.
- `.*?`**:** `.` matches any character but a newline. `*` is a meta-character and means *Repeat this 0 or more times*. `?` makes the `*` non-greedy, i.e., `.` will match up as few chars as possible before hitting a '['.
- `\[`**:**  `\` escapes special meta-characters, which in this case, is `[`. If we didn't do that, `[` would do something very weird instead.
- `(.*)`**:**  Parenthesis 'groups' whatever is inside it and you can later retrieve the groups by their numeric IDs or names (if they're given one).
- `\].*`**:**  You should know enough by now to know what this means.

### Implementation

First, import the `re` module -- it's not a built-in -- to where-ever you want to use the expression.

Then, use `re.search(regex_pattern, string_to_be_tested)` to search for the pattern in the string to be tested. This will return a `MatchObject` which you can store to a temporary variable. You should then call it's `group()` method and pass 1 as an argument (to see the 'Group 1' we captured using parenthesis earlier). I should now look like:

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = r'.*?\[(.*)].*'             #See Note at the bottom of the answer
>>> s = "foobar['infoNeededHere']ddd"
>>> match = re.search(pat, s)
>>> match.group(1)
"'infoNeededHere'"
```

### An Alternative

You can also use `findall()` to find all the non-overlapping matches by modifying the regex to `(?>=\[).+?(?=\])`.
- `(?<=\[)`**:**  `(?<=)` is called a look-behind assertion and checks for an expression *preceding* the actual match.
- `.+?`**:**  `+` is just like `*` except that it matches *one* or more repititions. It is made non-greedy by `?`.
- `(?=\])`**:**  `(?=)` is a look-*ahead* assertion and checks for an expression *following* the match w/o capturing it.
Your code should now look like:

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = r'(?<=\[).+?(?=\])'  #See Note at the bottom of the answer
>>> s = "foobar['infoNeededHere']ddd[andHere] [andOverHereToo[]"
>>> re.findall(pat, s)
["'infoNeededHere'", 'andHere', 'andOverHereToo[']
```

**Note:** Always use raw Python strings by adding an 'r' before the string (E.g.: `r'blah blah blah'`).

10x for reading! I wrote this answer when there were no accepted ones yet, but by the time I finished it, 2 ore came up and one got accepted. :( x<

Comment: This worked for me, PERFECT, thank you for the explanation as well.

Answer (score 19):

If there's only one of these `[.....]` tokens per line, then you don't need to use regular expressions at all:

```
In [7]: mystring = "Bacon, [eggs], and spam"

In [8]: mystring[ mystring.find("[")+1 : mystring.find("]") ]
Out[8]: 'eggs'
```

If there's more than one of these per line, then you'll need to modify Jarrod's regex `^.*\['(.*)'\].*$` to match multiple times per line, and to be non greedy. (Use the `.*?` quantifier instead of the `.*` quantifier.)

```
In [15]: mystring = "[Bacon], [eggs], and [spam]."

In [16]: re.findall(r"\[(.*?)\]",mystring)
Out[16]: ['Bacon', 'eggs', 'spam']
```