# strip out part of a string between reocurring characters using python

Tags: python

Using Python I am currently trying to strip out part of a string that occurs between two characters. The string can be different lengths, so character counting will not work. An example of what I am looking for would be:

```
172.-.221 - - [07/-20-:16:36:27 -0500] Firefox/17.0" ** 0 s/ 950 ms **
```

The desired section of the string is `0 s/ 950 ms`, and I have noticed that it occurs between the pairs of double asterisks (`** **`) consistently.

How would I grab just the part of the string between the two double asterisks (`**`)? How would I either output that to the screen or save that to a file?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Also, you might take a look at [this excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9891784/264775) for a similar case (the `**` was equivalent to brackets).

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly the sort of thing that re is made for. e.g.

```
import re

TheString = '172.-.221 - - [07/-20-:16:36:27 -0500] Firefox/17.0" ** 0 s/ 950 ms **'

wc = re.compile(r'\*\*(.*)\*\*')
matches = wc.findall(TheString)

#returns ['0 s/ 950 ms ']
```

Comment: You can also rewrite the second line in order take the spaces into account.  wc = re.compile(r'\\*\\* (.*) \\*\\*')

Comment: You can if desired - personally I would us `r'\*\* *(.*) *\*\*' so as to allow for a variable number of spaces.

Comment: Yes you will match any number of spaces, and all of them will be collected inside "matches" variable. That's not what user want. (According the question).

Comment: Oops use `r'\*\* *(.*) *\*\*'` lost a star - the match[1] will only give the part that excludes the **s and spaces.

Comment: You know what? I haven't tested ... but, that last pattern you post, don't look a little bit ambiguous to you? What if you change the last starts you add by +. Something like: 

    r'\*\* +(.*) +\*\*'

Comment: That would force a space be required rather than allowing 0 or more + you need to escape the *s to match them.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s='172.-.221 - - [07/-20-:16:36:27 -0500] Firefox/17.0" ** 0 s/ 950 ms **'
>>> s.split('**')[1].strip()
'0 s/ 950 ms'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `str.split` to extract it:

```
myString.split("**")[1]
```

This creates a list of strings by splitting the string at each appearance of `"**"`, then takes the second item, index `1`, from that list.

Answer (score 1):

This is good as well :)

```
>>> import re
>>> string = '172.-.221 - - [07/-20-:16:36:27 -0500] Firefox/17.0" ** 0 s/ 950 ms **'
>>> re.search('\*{2}(.+)\*{2}', string).group(1)
' 0 s/ 950 ms '
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions (the sub method). Here is a good tutorial by Google:
https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions