# Regular expression to match anything between two symbols

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Trying to understand more about regular expressions in **Python** and I find it difficult to **match any character (including newlines, tab characters, whitespaces, etc.) between two symbols, including those symbols**.

For example:

- `foobar89\n\nfoo\tbar; '''blah blah blah'8&^"'''` need to match `''blah blah blah'8&^"'''`
- `fjfdaslfdj; '''blah\n blah\n\t\t blah\n'8&^"'''` need to match `'''blah\n blah\n\t\t blah\n'8&^"'''`

(note, with the `\n` and `\t` symbols I signify the newlines and tab spaces in a text file)

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889635/regular-expression-to-return-all-characters-between-two-special-characters), I have tried this **`^.*\'''(.*)\'''.*$`** and this **`*?\'''(.*)\'''.*`** with no success.

Could someone guide me as to what I am doing wrong? I would appreciate any brief explanation as well.

Also, in order to understand the concept of *escaping of special characters*, I wonder if I by replacing the two symbols (e.g. from `'''` to `"""` or to `***`) in the regular expression it would still work (for a relevant string)?

e.g. for

- `fjfdaslfdj; """blah\n blah\n\t\t blah\n'8&^"""` need to match `"""blah\n blah\n\t\t blah\n'8&^"""`

**UPDATE**

Code I am trying to test the regexes on (taken & modified from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#writing-a-tokenizer)):

```
import collections
import re

Token = collections.namedtuple('Token', ['typ', 'value', 'line', 'column'])

def tokenize(code):
    token_specification = [
        # regexes suggested from [Thomas Ayoub][3]
        ('BOTH',      r'([\'"]{3}).*?\2'), # for both triple-single quotes and triple-double quotes
        ('SINGLE',    r"('''.*?''')"),     # triple-single quotes 
        ('DOUBLE',    r'(""".*?""")'),     # triple-double quotes 
        # regexes which match OK
        ('COM',       r'#.*'),
        ('NUMBER',  r'\d+(\.\d*)?'),  # Integer or decimal number
        ('ASSIGN',  r':='),           # Assignment operator
        ('END',     r';'),            # Statement terminator
        ('ID',      r'[A-Za-z]+'),    # Identifiers
        ('OP',      r'[+\-*/]'),      # Arithmetic operators
        ('NEWLINE', r'\n'),           # Line endings
        ('SKIP',    r'[ \t]+'),       # Skip over spaces and tabs
        ('MISMATCH',r'.'),            # Any other character
    ]

    test_regexes = ['COM', 'BOTH', 'SINGLE', 'DOUBLE']

    tok_regex = '|'.join('(?P<%s>%s)' % pair for pair in token_specification)
    line_num = 1
    line_start = 0
    for mo in re.finditer(tok_regex, code):
        kind = mo.lastgroup
        value = mo.group(kind)
        if kind == 'NEWLINE':
            line_start = mo.end()
            line_num += 1
        elif kind == 'SKIP':
            pass
        elif kind == 'MISMATCH':
            pass
        else:
            if kind in test_regexes:
                print(kind, value)
            column = mo.start() - line_start
            yield Token(kind, value, line_num, column)

f = r'C:\path_to_python_file_with_above_examples'

with open(f) as sfile:
    content = sfile.read()

for t in tokenize(content):
    pass #print(t)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with:

```
((['"]{3}).*?\2)
```

See [live running python](https://ideone.com/2PLzMm) or [live running regex](https://regex101.com/r/pF3uX1/2)

---

- `^.*\'''(.*)\'''.*$` => you added anchors to start/end of line which doesn't work in case of multi-line matching need
- `*?\'''(.*)\'''.*`  => syntax error
- `re.compile(ur'(([\'"]{3}).*?\2)', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)` => `re.DOTALL` makes `.` match new line.

Comment: It does work for `'''` but not for `"""` and I do not understand why. Could you perhaps add a brief explanation of why the 2 regular expressions I tried did not work (especially since I got them from another answer where they were working)? Also, why do I not need to 'escape' the symbols (i.e. `\'''`)?

Comment: Thanks for the edit and explanation. Could you also briefly address the other 2 things (matching other symbols like `"""` and the escaping of characters)? ..I just edited both my comment above and my question to add a similar example input-output for `"""`

Comment: @nk-fford you *need* to escape the special char that's your string delimiter: `"string with \" as delimiter don't need to escape ' char"` and `'string with \' as delimiter don\'t need to escape " char"`. Thus, see the escape in the regex. If you need to capture other symbol you can use [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: The character class very interesting. Just to be sure I get it right, say I want to match `"""bl"ah"\n 'blah'\n\t\t'8&^"""` from `"dasd a'\n\t """bl"ah"\n 'blah'\n\t\t'8&^"""  dasd a`, could you please show a regex for that?

Comment: @nk-fford try [here](https://regex101.com/r/pF3uX1/1). If you succeed, go to *code generator* and see python. If you fail, come back to me ;)

Comment: @nk-fford any feedback?

Comment: I try `r"('''.*?''')|"r'(""".*?""")` in order to match both cases of triple single quotes and triple double quotes but the latter fail in Python. Interestingly, they both work if try them on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pF3uX1/1). In Python, when I switch to `r"('''.*?''')|"r"(""".*?""")"` I get a `Statement expected, found BAD_CHARACTER` for the second `.*?` part. Any suggestions please?

Comment: @nk-fford I've added the char class & backreference so it won't match if the comment opening & closing uses different characters. If you use `ur'(([\'"]{3}).*?\2)'` within your code it should works

Comment: Again, your new regex works on the online tools, but errors when put in my python code. When I put `r'(([\'"]{3}).*?\2)'` in [this code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#writing-a-tokenizer) I get a `sre_constants.error: cannot refer to an open group at position 26`. :(

Comment: Update: I had to very slightly modify the regex to `r'([\'"]{3}).*?\2'` to avoid the error in my [code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#writing-a-tokenizer). Unfortunately, it still only matches the triple single-quotes but not the triple double-quotes. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Could you edit your question with your Python code please @nk-fford ?

Comment: I added the code I use with some comments in my question. Please see and help me gain understanding. Hopefully you could suggest the regexes to match triple single and triple double quotes successfully.