# Return string within a string based on expression 'x={(.*)}'

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that can vary but will always contain `x={stuffNeeded}`.

For example: `n=1,x={y,z,w},erore={3,4,5}` or `x={y,z,w}` or `erore={3,4,5},x={y,z,w}` etc.

I am having a devil of a time figuring out how to get `y,z,w`. The closest I got to finding the answer was based off of Yatharth's answer on this other post [Regular expression to return all characters between two special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889635/regular-expression-to-return-all-characters-between-two-special-characters).

It my searching I've so far come across something that almost worked. Testing was done here http://rubular.com/r/bgixv2J6yF and in python.

This was tested in python using:

```
i='n=1,x={y,z,w},erore={3,4,5}'
j='n=1,x={y,z,w}'
print re.search('x={(.*)}',i).group(1)
print re.search('x={(.*)}',j).group(1)
print re.search('x={(.*)}.',i).group(1)
print re.search('x={(.*)}.',j).group(1)
```

Result for the four different print:

```
'y,z,w'
'y,z,w},erore={3,4,5'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
'y,z,w'
```

Needed result is `'y,z,w'` for all cases and then if `x={*}` really isn't found I would put an error catch.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: is `x={yz,w}` a typo?

Comment: Upvoted for the phrase "a devil of a time" :D

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: it sure was a typo. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This regex does what you're trying to do :

```
regex = r'x={([^\}]*)}'
```

Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/OGaFkn/2)

**Explanation**

- **`{([^\}]*)`** : look for an opening bracket, then look for (and capture) any number of non `}` characters. So, your group 1 will contain the captured values for x.
- **`}`**: look for a closing bracket

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is that `{(.*)}` matches the longest string starting by `{` and ending by `}`, which in some cases is `y,z,w},erore={3,4,5`

You could use non-greedy matching by adding `?`. You don't need any other case.

```
import re

i='n=1,x={y,z,w},erore={3,4,5}'
j='n=1,x={y,z,w}'
expr = 'x={(.*?)}'
print (re.search(expr,i).group(1))
print (re.search(expr,j).group(1))
```

result:

```
y,z,w
y,z,w
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `re.findall` :

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('x={[^\}]*}', s)
```

#driver values :

```
IN : s = 'n=1,x={y,z,w},erore={3,4,5}'
OUT : ['x={y,z,w}']

IN : s = 'n=1,x={y,z,w}'
OUT : ['x={y,z,w}']

IN : s = 'x={y,z,w}'
OUT : ['x={y,z,w}']
```

---

Now to get the value of `x, y, z` , use `split` and `strip` :

```
>>> l = re.findall('x={[^\}]*}', s)

#if `l` is not empty
>>> out = l[0]
=> 'x={y,z,w}'

>>> y, z, x = out.strip('x={}').split(',')
>>> y, z, x
=> ('y', 'z', 'w')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = 'n=1,x={y,z,w},erore={3,4,5}'
final_data = re.findall('=\{(.*?)\}', s)
```

Output:

```
['y,z,w', '3,4,5']
```