# python: parse substring in brackets from string

Tags: python, parsing

What's a pythonic way to parse this string in the brackets:

```
txt = 'foo[bar]'
```

to get as result:

```
bar
```

What have I tried:

How I would solve it and I believe it's not very elegant:

```
result = txt.split('[')[1].split(']')[0]
```

I strongly think there is a library or method out there that has a more fault-tolerant and elegant solution for this. That's why I created this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to return all characters between two special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889635/regular-expression-to-return-all-characters-between-two-special-characters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

txt = 'foo[bar]'
print(re.findall(r"\[(.*?)\]", txt))
```

**Output:**

```
['bar']
```

Answer (score 0):

One out of many ways, using [slicing](https://www.pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/):

```
print(txt[4:].strip("[]"))
```

OR

```
import re

txt = 'foo[bar]'

m = re.search(r"\[([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\]", txt)
print(m.group(1))
```

OUTPUT:

```
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Another take on slicing, using `str.index` to find the locations of the starting and ending delimiters. Once you get a Python slice, you can just it just like an index into the list, except that the slice doesn't just give a single character, but the range of characters from the start to the end.

```
def make_slice(s, first, second):
    floc = s.index(first)
    sloc = s.index(second, floc)
    # return a Python slice that will extract the contents between the first
    # and second delimiters
    return slice(floc+1, sloc)

txt = 'foo[bar]'

slc = make_slice(txt, '[', ']')
print(txt[slc])
```

Prints:

```
bar
```