# Is there an function to get a string between chars?

Tags: python, string, replace, split

```py
input = "{1} {John Travis} {was} {here}"
```

Let's suppose that I want to get strings that are inside of the second and the third pair of brackets. So the expected output is:

```py
output = "John Travis was"
```

I tried to use array split with spaces as a separator, expecting as result something like:

```py
array = ["{1}", "{John Travis}", "{was}", "{here}"]

array[1] = re.sub("{", "", array[1])
array[1] = re.sub("}", "", array[1])

array[2] = re.sub("{", "", array[2])
array[2] = re.sub("}", "", array[2])

#expected result: array[1] + array[2] ( "John Travis was" )
```

But I remembered that I have the separator " " on 'John Travis', resulting:

```py
array = ["{1}", "{John", "Travis}", "{was}", "{here}"]

array[1] = re.sub("{", "", array[1])
array[2] = re.sub("}", "", array[2])

array = ["{1}", "John", "Travis", "{was}", "{here}"]

#unexpected result: array[1] + array[2] ( "John Travis" )
```

How to proceed?

Thanks for listening.

Comment: Did you consider `re.findall()` with a regexp that matches everything between `{` and `}`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression to return all characters between two special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889635/regular-expression-to-return-all-characters-between-two-special-characters)

Comment: The regexp is `\{[^}]*\}`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (without `re`), you can replace `{` with `'` and `}` with `',` and then use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to evaluate string as a tuple. Then you can use standard indexing:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

s = "{1} {John Travis} {was} {here}"

s = literal_eval(s.replace("{", "'").replace("}", "',"))
print(s[1], s[2])
```

Prints:

```
John Travis was
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate workaround with list comprehension:

```
input = "{1} {John Travis} {was} {here}"
print(*[i.strip('{}') for i in input.split()[1:-1]])

# John Travis was
```